# How do we search for multiple partial matches in a SQL query, each seperated by 'OR'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am coding a user search function for my site and currently it currently returns results but only for exact matches.

The current SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='$term' OR lastname='$term' OR url='$term' OR firstname='".$termExploded[0]."' ORDER BY hits DESC
```

How would I alter this query so that it also checks if the start of $term (or $termExploded[0] where relevant) matches a term?

This is what I came up with myself, but this doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='$term' LIKE '$term%' OR lastname='$term' LIKE '$term%' OR url='$term' LIKE '$term%' OR firstname='".$termExploded[0]."' LIKE '$term%' ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Thanks very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE firstname LIKE '$term%' OR
      lastname LIKE '$term%' OR
      url LIKE '$term%' OR
      firstname LIKE '$termExploded[0]%'
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Obviously you need to take care about properly escaping all the variables.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly and I see exactly what I did wrong. Yep the variables are all well escaped and sanitised!